# Headless chrome not identifying the GPU

Tags: chromium, playwright, google-chrome-headless

I'm running a headless Chrome in an Ubuntu 22.04 VM, and I'm struggling to make chrome identify my GPU. I'm using Playwright to launch a headless chrome instance.

My settings are:

```
chrome_args = [
    '--enable-features=Vulkan,UseSkiaRenderer',
    '--use-vulkan=swiftshader',
    '--enable-unsafe-webgpu',
    '--disable-vulkan-fallback-to-gl-for-testing',
    '--dignore-gpu-blocklist',
    '--use-angle=vulkan'
]
browser = playwright.chromium.launch(args=chrome_args, headless=True, channel="chrome")
```

However, when I render any objects e.g. when using Three.js with a sample scene, I get the error that WebGL2 is not enabled:

[image]

Screenshots below:

The screenshot of `chrome://gpu` [image: Screenshot]
Problems detected: [image: Problems]

Comment: Did you get anywhere? I've found I need to use cuda 11.7.1 to achieve 60fps screen recordings with webgl

Comment: @homerjam I found that using the following args helped, essentially falling onto `Vulkan` APIs: 
```
chrome_args = [
    "--use-angle=gl-egl",
    "--enable-features=Vulkan,UseSkiaRenderer",
    "--use-vulkan=native",
    "--enable-logging",
    "--disable-vulkan-fallback-to-gl-for-testing",
    "--ignore-gpu-blocklist"
]
```